# SQLite UPDATE если данные равны маске

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite, select, update

Есть таблица с 3 столбцами записи в которых равны соответственно диапазону 00-99, 000-999, 000-999. Я получаю 3 значения для этих столбцов, например 12, 123, 321 и мне нужно изменить некой другой столбец в этой таблице если значения которые я получил равны записи в таблице или вот запись может быть не только 00-99, 000-999, 000-999 а и еще иметь маску, например XX, XXX, XXX при котором изменить запись где столбцы от 00-99, 000-999, 000-999 если например X1, X2X, XXX то (11, 21 ... 91), (0-9,2,0-9), (0-9, 0-9, 0-9) вобщем X = от 0 до 9. Я пробывал сделать с LIKE но успехов нет( Как изменить запись что небудь в записи где полное соответствие и все записи где есть X выбрать диапазон от 1-9 вместо X?

Пример входных/выходных данных:

12, 234, 567 / запись со столбцами 12, 234, 567

1X, 234, 567 / записи со столбцами 1(1..9), 234, 567

X1, 2X4, 576 / записи со столбцами (1..9)1, 2(1-9)4, 576

Буду очень рад помощи

Таблицы:

```
CREATE TABLE `maps` (
`id`    INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
`state` INTEGER NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE `points` (
`id`    INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
`hour`  TEXT NOT NULL, // 00-99, XX, 0X, X5
`color` TEXT NOT NULL, // 000-999, 0X0, XXX
`property`  TEXT NOT NULL, // 000-999, XXX, X2X
`state` INTEGER NOT NULL);
```

Нужно сделать maps.state = points.state если все записи в таблице points которые могут быть от 00-99, 000-999, 000-999 и могут быть заданы маской имеют один и тотже state

Comment: Что-то типа `WHERE CAST(field AS TEXT) LIKE REPLACE(pattern, 'X', '_')`

Comment: @Akina напишете весь запрос?

Comment: @MikeWaters А вы не привели названия таблиц и полей, чтобы написать весь запрос.

Comment: @AK добавил....